# Spring Security OAuth2: Purge TokenStore

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Is there any way to configure Spring Security OAuth2 so it automatically purge TokenStore?

I want to remove the expired tokens from time to time. I've seen the InMemoryTokenStore code and it performs a flush every now and again.

But JdbcTokenStore does not perform any purge, so Who is in charge of removing the expried tokens from the storage?

I've implemented a TokenStore that uses MongoDB as storage, but I have the same problem. Nobody is removing the expired tokens from the storage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, `JdbcTokenStore` does not purge expired tokens automatically. It's up to you to purge old tokens.
Here's an idea how I would add such a mechanism.

`Expiration date` is part of [`OAuth2AccessToken`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/common/OAuth2AccessToken.html) which gets persisted as a serialized java object in the database. 
In order to detect whether an `OAuth2AccessToken` is eligible for deletion you would need to read it from the database an deserialize it.
This may lead to performance penalties where you need to purge a high amount of OAuth2AccessTokens.

My suggestion is to expand [`oauth_access_token`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql) table by a column `expiration` of type `TIMESTAMP` (H2 dialect) for saving expiration date.

```
create table oauth_access_token (
  token_id VARCHAR(256),
  token LONGVARBINARY,
  authentication_id VARCHAR(256),
  user_name VARCHAR(256),
  client_id VARCHAR(256),
  authentication LONGVARBINARY,
  refresh_token VARCHAR(256),
  expiration TIMESTAMP
);
```

Extend `JdbcTokenStore` and override `storeAccessToken` method. Don't forget to alter `insertAccessTokenSql` in order to honor new column `expiration` in the insert statement.

```
public void storeAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    String refreshToken = null;
    if (token.getRefreshToken() != null) {
        refreshToken = token.getRefreshToken().getValue();
    }

    if (readAccessToken(token.getValue())!=null) {
        removeAccessToken(token.getValue());
    }

    jdbcTemplate.update(insertAccessTokenSql, new Object[] { extractTokenKey(token.getValue()),
            new SqlLobValue(serializeAccessToken(token)), authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication),
            authentication.isClientOnly() ? null : authentication.getName(),
            authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId(),
            new SqlLobValue(serializeAuthentication(authentication)), extractTokenKey(refreshToken), token.getExpiration() }, new int[] {
            Types.VARCHAR, Types.BLOB, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.BLOB, Types.VARCHAR, Types.TIMESTAMP });
}
```

Enable Spring's [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) and add a scheduled method which purges old tokens.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
public void purgeOldTokens() {
    java.util.Date now = new Date();
    jdbcTemplate.update("delete from oauth_access_token where expiration <?", now);
}
```

Caution. This code just demonstrates my idea. I can't guarantee that there are no errors. Your code may and should vary from my example code.

Comment: Thanks ksokol. I guess we'll just have to bear the removal of expired tokens. I asked this question looking for an automate component inside Spring, but it seems there isn't anything like it

Comment: Now it seems jdbcTemplate has private access and we cannot do anything about it

Answer (score 0):

@ksokol Thank you very much!

Here is the working example of using CustomJdbcTokenStore

```
public class CustomJdbcTokenStore extends JdbcTokenStore {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private static final String INSERT_ACCESS_TOKEN_WITH_EXPIRATION_SQL = "insert into oauth_access_token (token_id, token, authentication_id, user_name, client_id, authentication, refresh_token, expiration) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)";
    private static final String INSERT_REFRESH_TOKEN_WITH_EXPIRATION_SQL = "insert into oauth_refresh_token (token_id, token, authentication, expiration) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    
    public CustomJdbcTokenStore(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void storeAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        String refreshToken = getRefreshToken(token);
        if (this.readAccessToken(token.getValue()) != null) {
            this.removeAccessToken(token.getValue());
        }
        final DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator defaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator = new DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator();

        this.jdbcTemplate.update(
                INSERT_ACCESS_TOKEN_WITH_EXPIRATION_SQL,
                new Object[]{this.extractTokenKey(token.getValue()),
                        new SqlLobValue(this.serializeAccessToken(token)),
                        defaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication),
                        authentication.isClientOnly() ? null : authentication.getName(),
                        authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId(),
                        new SqlLobValue(this.serializeAuthentication(authentication)),
                        this.extractTokenKey(refreshToken), token.getExpiration()},
                new int[]{Types.VARCHAR, Types.BLOB, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.BLOB, Types.VARCHAR, Types.TIMESTAMP});
    }

    private String getRefreshToken(OAuth2AccessToken token) {
        if (token.getRefreshToken() != null) {
            return token.getRefreshToken().getValue();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void storeRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        final DefaultExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken oAuth2RefreshToken = (DefaultExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken) refreshToken;
        this.jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_REFRESH_TOKEN_WITH_EXPIRATION_SQL, new Object[]{this.extractTokenKey(refreshToken.getValue()), new SqlLobValue(this.serializeRefreshToken(refreshToken)), new SqlLobValue(this.serializeAuthentication(authentication)), oAuth2RefreshToken.getExpiration()}, new int[]{Types.VARCHAR, Types.BLOB, Types.BLOB, Types.TIMESTAMP});
    }
   
}}
```